# A "What's my vector?" game

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, puzzle

Alice chooses a binary vector $V$ of length $n$ which is unknown to Bob.  In each round Bob can choose any number of indices $i$ and then Alice tells Bob how many of the $V_i$ are set to $1$.   The game terminates when Bob can say with certainty exactly which binary vector Alice has. Alice  would like the game to go on as long as possible and Bob would like to make it as short as possible.

What are Alice and Bob's best strategies and how long does the game take?

For $n=7$ the following strategy always works.

Bob chooses indices 35, 234, 24567, 12356,14567 . This takes $5$ rounds.

For $n=10$ the following strategy always works.

Bob chooses indices 1-3-4-5-6-7-8, 3-5-9, 1-2-3-8-10,1-2-4-5-9-10,1-2-5-7-8, 1-2-3-4-5-8-10, 2-4-7-8-10. This takes $7$ rounds.

Comment: Alice has only one move, which is to choose the binary vector. After that, she has to react deterministically to Bob. Alice's best strategy is to maximize the entropy of the vector, which she can do by randomly setting $n/2$ entries to 0 and $n/2$ entries to 1.

Comment: Is there any strategy for Bob that would terminate in less than $n$ steps? Or maybe Bob does not know $n$ either?

Comment: @gt6989b Bob knows $n$.  Maybe he needs $n$ steps in the worst case, I don't know.

Comment: So what is the metric which you are using to compare strategies? Best case? Worst case? Average case? If average, do you assume each input from Alice has equal weight?

Comment: @gt6989b The metric is the worst case for Bob. If Alice's strategy is random then it is also interesting to look at the average case over whatever distribution Alice has chosen assuming Bob chooses perfectly.

Comment: @Carl It seems one query might give you $\log_2{n}$ bits of information following your line of reasoning.  Does this mean you can always solve the problem in less than $n$ queries?

Comment: @marshall $n$ is certainly an upper bound since you can query each index (each bit) on its own exactly once and end up with perfect information. The difficult part is that, even though the first query might give you $\log_2 n$ bits of information, subsequent queries should be made contingent on the result of the first, to play optimally. I haven't come up with a good way of doing this yet.

Comment: @Carl Suppose $n=2$ and Alice does as you suggest in your comment, and selects randomly one bit to be $1$ and the other to be $0$.  If Bob knew that Alice had this strategy, then Bob could be "done" in one turn, by asking about the first bit. Does this suggest for Alice's particular randomizing strategy that Bob can beat using $n$ steps?

Comment: For $n=5$, it suffices to ask $4$ questions, and these can be independent of the answers: $12345$, $123$, $34$, $24$.

Comment: @coffeemath Given the problem, we have to assume that Bob has no information about Alice's strategy. He can try to guess her strategy, but then this turns into a game of poker (play the person, not the cards) and things change a lot. If Alice assumes that Bob has no information about her strategy, her strategy should be to pick one random bit to be $1$ if $n = 2$. In this case Bob has to make $2$ moves -- one to determine how many bits are set and one to determine which bit is set.

Comment: @Carl I see your point. I was going on the idea that one player should choose a strategy so that, even if the other player knows the strategy, it still does as well as possible. Likely I'm confusing something I heard about games/strategies.

Comment: @coffeemath You also have a good point there. Then I'd say the strategy should be for Alice to flip a coin for each bit -- i.e. set each bit to $1$ with probability $1/2$. On average half the bits will now be $1$ and even if Bob has all the information about Alice's strategy, he still has to do a lot of work. If, for example, Alice set exactly one bit to $1$, Bob would need to make only $\log_2 n$ moves to find it, which is much better than having to make $n$ moves.

Comment: I would suggest to concentrate first on the variant in which Alice is allowed to “cheat” and make up the vector while playing as long as all of her past answers stay consistent.

Comment: Another variant is that Bob has to decide on all of his questions in advance. So far we do not know if this makes a difference (in the worst case or the case of a “cheating” alice as described a minute ago). The question would then be to find a minimum number $m$ of vectors $q^j\in\{0,1\}^n$ such that $\{0,1\}^n\to\mathbb N^m$, $v\mapsto(\langle v,q^j\rangle)_j$ is injective. I think that this minimum is $m=n$ for $n<5$ and $m=4$ for $n=5$ (see earlier comment).

Comment: Note, the OP has asked an equivalent version of this at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151390/how-to-find-counterfeit-coins-by-weighing

Comment: This problem was solved (up to a small multiplicative factor) [by Erdos and Renyi](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-12.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Under the following two assumptions, this question comes down to [experimental design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design) (in the information theoretic sense).

1. Bob is allowed to use the information after moves $1, 2, \ldots, k-1$ to determine move $k$.
2. Alice either chooses and sticks to a binary vector, $V$, or is allowed to change bits before each of Bob's moves -- that is, before she knows which indices Bob will pick next -- as long as the changes are consistent with Bob's existing information. (Information theoretically, the case where Alice is not allowed to change bits and the case where Alice is allowed to change bits without knowing what Bob will do next are equivalent.)

There is a true state of $V$ that Bob is trying to discover through measurements. Each experiment entails Bob selecting a set of indices, based on the information that he has already, and then discovering at how many of those indices there are ones in $V$. Bob's experimental design question, at any step, is *At which indices should I measure next so as to maximize the expected information gain from the measurement?*

This is equivalent to the question, *Which choice of indices maximizes the entropy of the probability distribution over possible outcomes at those indices?* The base-2 entropy of a discrete random variable, $X$, with $m$ possible outcomes $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\}$, that are distributed according to the probability mass function, $P(x_i)$, is defined as
$$
H_2(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^m P(x_i)\log_2 P(x_i)
$$
In this case, the possible outcomes are the different possible integer answers that Bob can get when asking Alice how many entries in $V$ are $1$ for a given set of indices and $P(x_i)$ gives the probability of getting each of the possible integer answers.

For example, let's say $n=4$ and Bob already knows that the total number of $1$ bits is $3$. We write this as
$$A(1,2,3,4) = 3$$
meaning the answer that Alice gives when asked how many of bits $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$ are set. What is the expected information gain if Bob next asks for $A(1)$ or $A(1,2)$ or $A(1,2,3)$ or $A(1,2,3,4)$? (These are the only questions Bob has to consider since all others follow from symmetry.)
$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
         & P(x_i)                                           & H_2(X) \\
\hline
A(1)     & \left\{0: \frac{1}{4},\ 1: \frac{3}{4}\right\} & 2 - \frac{3\log_2 3}{4} \approx 0.81 \\
A(1,2)   & \left\{1: \frac{1}{2},\ 2: \frac{1}{2}\right\} & 1 \\
A(1,2,3) & \left\{2: \frac{3}{4},\ 3: \frac{1}{4}\right\} & 2 - \frac{3\log_2 3}{4} \approx 0.81 \\
A(1,2,3,4) & \left\{3: 1\right\} & 0
\end{array}
$$
This means that Bob's best move is to ask for $A(1,2)$ -- or any other 2-index set, by symmetry -- since that is the move that maximizes the expected information gain. Note that the expected information gain from $A(1,2,3,4)$ is $0$ since we already have deterministic information about the value of that measurement. After learning the value of $A(1,2)$, Bob has a new constraint on the possible values of different measurements, can update the probability distributions associated with those measurements, recalculate their entropies and determine his next move.

Comment: How do we know this greedy approach for Bob is optimal? Maybe he should choose a suboptimal move now so that he can make a  better one later on and learn more information overall?

Comment: @marshall This approach is provably optimal because it uses all the information that Bob has available at a given step, to make the decision that leads to the greatest expected information gain. This is optimal in the sense that, under the probability distribution over possible outcomes, it will lead to the smallest expected number of measurements. Note that these are all expected values and probability distributions, which means there is uncertainty, but that is the best we can do with limited information. I suggest you read more at the link in the first paragraph.

Comment: Can it be used to give bounds for how long the game lasts for?

Comment: Say we are playing a similar game, where we have a fixed set of vectors in $\mathbb N^3$, Alice chooses one and Bob is allowed to ask for any of the three components of the vector. Say the vectors are (in abbreviated notation) $111,121,132,142,211,226,233,242,314,325,333,343,414,425,434,445$. What would your theory suggest that the first question should be?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I'm not sure I understand exactly, but I'll try to answer your question. Alice chooses a vector from $\mathbb{N}^3$ -- that's all right. And Bob is presumably trying to determine the value of the vector. Does Alice still tell Bob the sum of entries in the vector? If this is the case, the best strategy depends on the probability distribution over $\mathbb{N}$ with which Alice chooses each of the vector components (assuming they're independent). In the binary problem this distribution was assumed to be $\{0: 1/2,\ 1: 1/2\}$.

Comment: I am sorry if I did not state my example clearly enough. I wanted
Alice to choose one of the $16$ vectors given, and Bob was not to ask
for sums of entries but just for entries.  In this example if you ask
for the first or second entry you narrow down the selection to four,
if you ask for the third entry you narrow it down to three (or even
one in case the answer is $6$).

Comment: [continued] So if I understand it correctly, then
your procedure will suggest to ask for the third entry. However, you
will then (in case the vector is not $226$) still have to ask two more
questions to know what the vector is. On the other hand it suffices to
ask for the first two entries to know the vector. So in this example
your procedure would indeed be too greedy, a possibility which
@marshall mentioned. So it seems to me that you give a useful
heuristic, but no proof of anything.